# User defined/dynamic layouts and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to create several fragments that represents visual "modules" into my app. Each fragment is a sort of view in to different features of the app.

It would be really nice if the user could essentially move the fragments around visually like more modern desktop like apps allow.

Essentially it boils down to allowing the user to modify an activity.xml's layout visually(drag around).

e.g., the layout is

```
ab
xy
```

but they can grab, say, a handle on b and drag it to the lower corner x to get

```
ax
by
```

etc. Possibly they could overlap if the user doesn't drag to replace(so a z-index would be required).

Is this possible to do with android, and if so, what will it take to accomplish? I guess it's just a matter of some layout logic and setting the controls?